Confusion about variations of h_FE and h_fe
This datasheet gives a map of the relation between \$I_C\$ and \$h_{FE}\$ normalised. Does this mean even for the "same" BJTs, their \$h_{FE}\$ can be quite different? Like, 2N3903 in this datasheet. Can 2 2N3903 transsitors have remarkably different \$h_{FE}\$ under the same condition (like the same temperature, \$I_C\$, etc.)?

However, for \$h_{fe}\$, they give an exat-number version of the relation map, as seen in the picture below. This is not a normalised version. Does this mean 2 BJT transsitors of the same "model" (for example, 2N3903) have (almost) the same \$h_{fe}\$ under the same condition (like the same temperature, \$I_C\$, etc.)?


Interesting question. But the answer is that two of the same BJT types will have a different H_FE and h_fe value. What you see is a "typical" value. But no one has ever seen a typical transistor just as you'll never meet a typical "man".

Also, you should not worry much about the difference between H_FE and h_fe. Because H_FE is not a well-controlled parameter, it varies a lot from transistor to transistor of the same type. So in the designing process, we usually pick the minimum value of a H_FE and we assume that H_FE = h_fe.

The second graph (of hfe) is quite clearly labeled TYPICAL.

The only thing you need to know about Hfe is that it varies, and varies a lot, so you cannot assume any given value as the Ic, Vce, temperature, and device varies.
When you design a transistor circuit and bias it, your bias circuit must allow for Hfe to vary from the datasheet minimum to infinity, while the transistor stays in the region you want (whether linear amplifying, saturated, whatever). If you do not allow for this variation, eventually your circuit will be upset by a change of temperature or device.

The static (i.e. DC) common-emitter current gain is denoted by \$h_{FE}\$, while \$h_{fe}\$ is the dynamic common-emitter current gain. The relationship between the two current gains is as follows:
$$
h_{fe}(I_c) 
    = \frac {h_{FE}(I_c)}
            {1 - (I_{cb0} + I_b) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial I_c}h_{FE}(I_c) }
$$
relative variation of \$h_{fe}\$:
$$
\frac{\Delta h_{fe}}{h_{fe}}
    = \frac{ h_{fe}(I_c) - h_{FE}(I_c) }{ h_{fe}(I_c)}
    = \frac{I_c}{h_{FE}} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial I_c} h_{FE}(I_c)
$$
You can find this formula in all electronics books, for example the good old Millman and Halkias text Electronic Devices and Circuits.

Reference for this formula?

You can find it in all electronics books, for example the good old Millman and Alkias text "Electronic Devices and Circuits.

@IcenFire It’s in Millman and Halkias’s Integrated Electronics, page 144, equation (5-23).

\$h_{FE}\$ is DC gain absolute but normalized to 100% at 25'C at max hFE which tends to peak at 10% of Imax in most transistors.  Here 160 @ 10mA is the nominal value while the tables spec the min to max range.
\$h_{fe}\$ is AC gain incremental gain \$d/dIc * h_{FE}\$ vs Ic from 0.1 mA to that peak.
What @Neil doesn't say is that you must some method of feedback to stabilize DC bias pt with hFE and use hfe for AC gain.  Some reference is needed too to control hFE, so a current source into a diode is controlled by Vcc/R to generate a predictable voltage and current up to 1 mA. But after this, Vf becomes(/has already become) dependent on bulk resistance. Vf+If*rb.
Op Amps internally use current mirrors to keep hFE regulated OR use a circuit that is only affected by Vbe(Ic) and not hFE(Ic).
But hFE is for DC bias and hfe is for AC gain.

Quote: "But hFE is for DC bias and hfe is for AC gain.". In a well designed circuit the ac gain is determined by gm (transconductance). The parameter hfe determines the resulting base current , and hence, the input resistance only.

So when gm​=Ic/Vt and  Ic has a large Ic swing, how does that work with this design?  https://tinyurl.com/274rzyyz Help me understand
